# Why does English sound so cold to a Slavic speaker?

Tags: english, germanic-languages, russian, slavic-languages

When you compare English with e.g .Russian or some other Slavic language, English sounds very cold and not warming at all. Could it be explained scientifically?

Compare this in Russian:

http://youtu.be/MKGH2tmrp08?t=9m22s

And this in English:

http://youtu.be/LgaakhgbL9s?t=3m15s

Russian to me sounds more "human" and warm. Could it be scientifically explain?

Comment: I don't think you can measure a "warm" language and a "cold" one in a scientific manner as it's a subjective classification and every person sees things differently. Unless you give an objective definition of what you mean by "cold" and "warm", this question is more tending to opinions than facts.

Comment: I think it is the phonotactic suitablity effect-- after you learn a language you get a feel for what is a valid word (even if it isn't in the lexicon). Absd sounds wrong in english (illegal consonant clusters), but is fine in Russian (Absd is the name of a Russian  mathematician). So when you are exposed to a foreign language, your brain is telling you "that doesn't sound right, it's violating all the phonotactic rules" and after a long while you get used to it & it starts to sound right. In your case, eventually English would sound right and Frisian and Dutch will sound wrong.

Comment: Right. And English is also quite rigid about word order, whereas in Russian word order is freely variable for lots of purposes, including emotive display.

Comment: I would not say English is cold, I would say it is "wooden".

Comment: Some people are reading this question as though it's making an absolute judgement that English is a cold language and Russian is a warm language. When in fact it is specifically asking why English seems relatively cold from a Russian speaker's point of view. Just as English speakers find German to be harsh but German speakers don't. I think these are sound psycholinguistic questions. Maybe the question could do with some adjusting to clarify this though?

Comment: @hippietrail I agree that English is not the coldest language. Probably German and Swedish or something like that is the coldest. But it's definitely coldest than Spanish or French. Notice that in Spanish or French you have the soft "L" while in English you don't have that. Not to mention a big "warm"effect in Slavic languages and their soft version of d,t,n,l which are  ď,ť,ň,ľ. English has only ť and ň. It's very funny and (cold) when an Englishman tries to say "deti" = children. It sounds very hard (like combining "de-"mocracy and "tee" not soft like this http://youtu.be/HbWwWYvfNX0?t=1m40s

Comment: In Slavic languages you also have more masculine and feminine words and also 3 grades or more of diminutives. In English you have 2 max and only for certain words. E.g. Suzanne and the "softer" form is Suzie. In Slavic languages you can say this: Coldest(official) Zuzana, warmer is Zuzanka or Zuzka and warmest ist Zuzička or Zuzanôčka or Zuzinka or Zuzulienka, Zuzančička etc. You can use it also for casual things like dog. In English you have only doggy. We can say 1.pes(dog), psík(doggie), psíček(more doggie :). And check soft sounds (ď,ť,ň,ľ) http://youtu.be/BhaUeOsb2v0

Comment: From the opposite point of view I can tell you that Slavic languages, especially Russian sounds "backwards" to English speakers. Another word that comes to mind is "dribbly" with all the "y" sounds from palatalization and iotation. English actually has quite a range of diminutives, some more productive than others but most pretty informal. There is a further degree of diminuteive for "dog" but it's very childish, ["doggy woggy"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doggy_woggy). You could also analyse "pup", "puppy", "pooch", "poochikins", etc as "suppletive" diminutives.

Comment: @hippietrail ;D What about "zmrzlina"," skrz" or "zdrvujuci". I guess you have trouble to pronounce that if you are from EN ;D http://youtu.be/Xf6T0FziKb4

Comment: This question begins with a subjective judgment ("English is colder than Slavic languages") and asks for a specific reason for that judgment. Well, nobody knows what happened in your childhood, so there you go. I vote close.

Answer (score 4):

Although I am quite fluent in Russian, I wouldn't say English sound particularly 'cold' to me. There can be many different personal  explanations on why we like or dislike certain languages: childhood imprinting, personal idiosyncrasy, aversion to or preferences towards certain languages - you name it.

But the psycholinguistic reason may be that Russian in fact offers a greater number of options of intonational patterns than English does. In Russian, the intonation actually  conveys syntactical meaning covering the speakers's personal attitude towards the things said (or towards an addressee).

The difference may be also in MBTI-types of the actors (the Russian actors are more like  Feeling types).

Also, please notice that while both stories cover the same archetypical scenarios (journey into a mirror, meeting doppelgängers and going through labyrinths), they are different and the Russian story is a bit secondary to Carrol's book, for it partially borrows the original idea (namely, travel through a mirror).

These ideas are well synthesised with Slavic archetypes of journeys to another world and were later developed in many Russian books.

Answer (score 1):

I agree completely with the comment by @Alenanno, Jun 29 at 15:07. But you had asked for some scientific evaluation, so here it is.

I came across a paper by Stephanie Lindemann, [Who speaks “broken English”? US undergraduates’ perceptions of non-native English](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1473-4192.2005.00087.x/full), that, as the title says, deals with the converse phenomenon. "respondents were given a list of 58 countries and asked to rate the English of university students from each of these countries on how correct, friendly, and pleasant they found it on a scale of 1 to 10." The study covers accents from France, Italy, Germany, Russia, India, Mexico, and China.

Many AmE speakers commented that a Russian accent sounds "harsh", "hard", "guttural", "very forceful and damaging to the throat". Does this make a statement about Slavic/Russian itself, or about how Slavic/Russian is *perceived* by American students? I am, of course, assuming that these perceptions would stay the same whether a Russian is speaking English or speaking Russian.

Comment: Check this unique Slavic dialect from Slovakia : http://youtu.be/eBDry5kVfmU . Modern Slovak language is based on this dialect. English doesn't have e.g. Ľ,Ť so some things like "I love you" sounds cold. For me it sounds similar like for you "Ich liebe dich!" a little harsh (unless it's told by a German supermodel ;). "Ľúbim ťa" or "Я люблю тебя" sounds less harsh. In Slovak, we have a word "ľubozvučnosť" something like "euphony" and it's very typical for the Slovak language. Another examples http://youtu.be/vE8w31-35Go or http://youtu.be/HKLbnqhXaIo

Comment: @Derfder: My own perceptions vary vastly, from speaker to speaker. I have come across, what is to me, pleasant and unpleasant examples of each of these languages and English accents. I am at a loss when asked for an overall evaluation.

Comment: @Derfder: I will add that if a person sounds harsh to me in one language, ei sounds the same in each language ei speaks. And likewise, for people who sound pleasant to me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that Russian is a much more tonal language than English. Therefore, Russians use tone more to convey meaning, feelings, size, etc... As a result, English sounds like it has less life, because there is less tonality in English speech.

Also, the use of suffixes in Russian often allow one to associate a word with the one following it. As a result, there is more of a sense of flow in Russian speech, which also gives it that more "lifelike" quality when compared to English.

Just my 2 cents worth as a fluent bilingual speaker of both languages that shares the OP's sentiment.

Comment: WRT "Russian is a much more tonal language than English. Therefore, Russians use tone more to convey meaning, feelings, size, etc." Neither Russian nor English are tonal languages. Speakers of practically all languages use intonation. The same applies to cross-word coarticulatory effects, whether triggered by suffixes or not.

Comment: Yes, but in Russian, intonation can change the meaning of the sentence (e.g., from statement to question).

Comment: And that is different from English?

Comment: @prash Perhaps Michael means that intonation is more often distinctive. Whereas English inverts a sentence into TSPO word order (like Welsh declaratives) to mark it as a question, Russian is freer from the start and presumably needs some other cue.